# ¿Cómo puedo hacer intent en xamarin.Forms cross platform?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-intent

Estoy haciendo una aplicación móvil para Android e IOS donde tengo botones en una vista xaml, cada botón tiene una función específica, por ejemplo, ir a un perfil de instagram específico (abriendo la app de instagram instalada en el móvil), ir a gmail, etc

He encontrado la forma de hacer intent en xamarin basado en proyectos para android pero la forma en la que asignan el ID para cada boton en el archivo Main.axml no lo puedo hacer en mi vista xaml de plataforma cruzada.

alguna sugerencia?

gracias!

Comment: Xamarin.Forms no hace intent, eso es propio de Android y lo podes usar en Xamarin.Android. Mira la pagina oficial de Xamarin y ahi tenes la clase essential y ahi tenes la clases para hacer todo tipo de acciones que deberias hacerla de forma manual en cada plataforma con DependencyService. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials?view=xamarin-essentials

Comment: Amigo @RamiroBarone muy agradecida. Eso que comentas es lo mismo que yo habia leído pero estaba un poco confundida sobre su uso en la plataforma.. Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo por completo la pregunta, si estás preguntando como hacer un Intent para IOS y que funcione de la misma manera que en Android, la respuesta es que no funciona de la misma manera, pero hay algunas [formas de trabajar de manera similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630874/is-there-android-intent-concept-in-iphone-sdk). Personalmente tuve que hacer un [Intent implícito](https://nbortolotti.blogspot.com/2011/05/utilizando-intents-implicitos-para.html) hace un tiempo para que mi app fuera una opción para recibir información de otras apps, lo cual fué sencillo en Android, pero para hacerlo en IOS tuve que agregar el siguiente método en mi AppDelegate:

```
 public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
    {
        string p = url.Path;


        using (var memOfPdf = new System.IO.MemoryStream())//Using es para hacer un dispose automático al stream
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(p, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                fs.CopyTo(memOfPdf);

                var docsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); //Directorio común para documentos

                var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(docsPath, Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(p));
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, memOfPdf.ToArray());
            }
        }


        return true;
    }
```

Y además agregar el siguiente código a mi Info.plist para que mi app aceptara ciertos formatos (PDF):

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PDF</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        </array>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Default</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

De verdad espero haber ayudado :) .